# Directed to someone

Tags: word-usage

If there's a group of people and person A starts to speak with B only, is it correct to say:

> When A explained the problem, he directed to B only.

And is there a more natural way of saying this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify *what* is being directed. For instance, you could say any of the folllowing:

- *When A explained the problem, he directed his attention towards B alone.*
- *When A explained the problem, he spoke directly to B.*
- *A's explanation of the problem was directed primarily towards B*